# How to lock UITextField input to accept only ONE letter from A to Z on SWIFT

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitextfield, letter

I have an UITextField named "TextField" and I want to get only one letter form A to Z. User will not enter more than 1 letter on this TextField. How can I do this?

Comment: Please tell us what you have you tried.

Answer (score 2):

In order to control user input into a `UITextField`, you must implement the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol in your controller.

[UITextFieldDelegate Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/)

In particular, look into `textField(_:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:)` and return a `Bool` value that allows the character or not.